# Enable/Disable account programmatically using Python ldap module?

Tags: python, ldap

I would like to programmatically enable/disable LDAP user accounts.  From the command prompt I can use dsutil and this apparently sets/removes the nsAccountLock operational attribute.  I have attempted to do modify_s() to set and remove this attribute from w/in Python but always get the following error message:  "Insufficient 'write' privilege to the 'nsAccountLock' attribute of entry ''".

Is there a way to set/remove/add operational attributes or otherwise enable/disable ldap users programmatically through Python?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 8):

You should use the attribute 'userAccountControl' which contains a set of control bits.

If you are managing normal users, to enable user:

```
userAccountControl = 512
```

and to disable it:

```
userAccountControl = 514
```

Generally, if you want to enable/disable an existing user, you should retrieve current value and update it this way.

```
userADAccountControlFlag = 2
userAccountControl = user.userAccountControl

# To enable user:
userAccountControl = userAccountControl & ~userADAccountControlFlag # (& bit-wise AND, ~ bit-wise Negate)

# To disable user:
userAccountControl = userAccountControl | userADAccountControlFlag # (| bit-wise OR)

user.userAccountControl = userAccountControl

# Then update user on ldap server
```

you can find more about userAccountControl attribute here: http://www.selfadsi.org/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm

Comment: Any idea how to do this via ldap3? I am getting `ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type userAccountControl`

Comment: @Atul the attribute is specific to ActiveDirectory regardless of the protocol implementation; erf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties. You should know that ldap3 library exposes two different core and abstract APIs. In the first one, LDAP returns an array for each attribute which you need to access as `entries[0]['userAccountControl'][0]`