# Get user status (disabled or active) in Active Directory with ldap3 Python

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

I am getting a list of all users in Active Directory and I need to check their status — if the user is active or disabled. I expect that **userAccountControl** should return user status, but I get only 512 for all users but one (who returns 66048) and this is not correlated with user status (as far as I know).

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection

serverName = 'LDAP://server'
domainName = 'name'
userName = 'superuser'
password = 'password'
base = 'longString'

server = Server(serverName)
conn = Connection(server, read_only=True, user='{0}\\{1}'.format(domainName, userName), password=password, auto_bind=True)

conn.search(base, '(objectclass=person)', attributes=['displayName', 'mail', 'userAccountControl','sAMAccountName'])

for i in conn.entries:
    print 'USER = {0} : {1} : {2}'.format(i.sAMAccountName.values[0], i.displayName.values[0], i.userAccountControl.values[0])
```

> USER = ABC : John Smith : 512
>   USER = DEF : Sarah Connor : 514
>   USER = GHI : Thomas Anderson : 66048

Is it a correct way to get user status? Is there any other way to check AD user status with some application with UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [userAccountControl flags](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-the-useraccountcontrol-flags-to-manipulate-user-account-pro):

512 - Normal account (512),

514 - Disable account (2 + 512),

66048 - Normal account + dont expire password (65536 + 512).

Comment: A better method is described at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27246133/88122